# Spring Boot 1.3 WebSocket JSON converter Produces Invalid JSON

Tags: grails, spring-boot

After upgrading to Spring Boot 1.3 (via Grails 3.1), the JSON output is rendered incorrectly. I believe it is because of the [new auto-configured WebSocket JSON converter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/204cb6f195ce5d6779ab63887252f2d1a69aa6f9).

For example, with previous versions of Spring Boot (via Grails 3.0), using the following code:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat")
@SendTo("/sub/chat")
protected String chatMessage() {
    def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    builder {
        type("message")
        text("foobar")
    }
    builder.toString()
}
```

This would produce:

```
{"type": "message", "text": "foobar"}
```

With Spring Boot 1.3 (via Grails 3.1), that web socket produces the following:

```
"{\"type\":\"message\",\"text\":\"foobar\"}"
```

This is not valid JSON.  How can I get rid of this new behavior and have it render the JSON as it was before? Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

I tried overriding the new `configureMessageConverters` method, but it did not have any effect.

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are right. referenced commit shows questionable autoconfiguration imho.

especially b/c in the past, the converter ordering was intentionally changed to that `StringMessageConverter` takes precedence before `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/670c216d3838807fef46cd28cc82165f9abaeb45

for now, you can either disable that autoconfiguration:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration])
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration { ... }
```

or, you add yet another `StringMessageConverter` to the top of the configured converters (maybe because you do want the boot autoconfiguration behavior because it is using the jackson `ObjectMapper` bean instead of creating a new one):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        messageConverters.add 0, new StringMessageConverter()
        return true
    }

...

}
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in Grails but in Java you have to now pass the object instead of an object in the String class.  I believe the old behavior was actually incorrect as it was returning a string as an object so there was no way to return a String that had JSON inside it as a String. So create an object with the structure you want and return it and you should be fine.   I went through the same issue when upgrading from 1.2.X to 1.3.X. I am not exactly sure what change caused this but I think in the long run it is the correct thing to do.